# Unique SAT is in DP

Tags: complexity-theory

I am an engineer learning about the complexity class DP, and I am looking at a number of sources that mention that UNIQUE-SAT and CRITICAL-SAT are both in DP. Is there a proof of this fact somewhere that I can learn from?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the definition: $\phi$ is in UNIQUE-SAT if and only if
$$\underbrace{\phi\in\mathrm{SAT}}_{\text{NP property}}\text{ and not }(\underbrace{\text{$\phi$ has at least two satisfying assignments}}_{\text{NP property}}).$$

Likewise: a CNF $\phi=\bigwedge_{i<n}C_i$ is in CRITICAL-SAT if and only if
$$\Bigl(\underbrace{\text{$\bigwedge_{i\ne j}C_i$ is satisfiable for each $j$}}_{\text{NP property}}\Bigr)\text{ and not }\underbrace{\phi\in\mathrm{SAT}}_{\text{NP property}}.$$
To see that the property in brackets is in NP, it can be witnessed by a sequence of $n$ assignments, where the $j$th assignment satisfies all clauses except $C_j$.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

They are defined and proved to be in $D^P$ in the original article by Papadimitriou and Yannakakis, *The complexity of facets (and some facets of complexity)* published in JCSS in 1984 ([Volume 28, Issue 2, April 1984, Pages 244-259](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000084900680)).

Critical-SAT is defined in a follow-up article by Papadimitriou and Wolfe *The complexity of facets resolved* published in JCSS in 1988 ([Volume 37, Issue 1, August 1988, Pages 2-13](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900426)).

---

The complexity class $D^P$ is essentially languages that are the intersection of a language in $\text{NP}$ and a language in $\text{co-NP}$.

A couple of $D^P$-complete problems:

- SAT-UNSAT: Input is two SAT formulae $\Phi_S$ and $\Phi_U$ and the question is whether $\Phi_S$ is satisfiable and $\Phi_U$ is unsatisfiable.
- Minimal unsatisfiability: Input is a 3-CNF-SAT formula $\Phi$.  Question: Is it true that $\Phi$ is unsatisfiable, but removing any clause at all makes the resulting formula satisfiable?
- Exact clique: Input is a graph $G$ and an integer $k$.  Question: Does the largest clique in $G$ have size $k$?
- Critical clique: Input is a graph $G$ and an integer $k$.  Question: Is it true that $G$ does not have a $k$-clique, but if you add any edge at all, then the resulting graph will have a $k$-clique?
- Maximum non-hamiltonian graph:  Input is a graph $G$.  Question: Is it true that $G$ is non-hamiltonian but adding any edge at all to graph results in a hamiltonian graph?
- Minimal 3-colorability:  Input is a graph $G$.  Question: Is it true that $G$ is not 3-colorable, but deleting any vertex at all results in a 3-colorable graph?